# In python is it possible to change the first line of the csv file using to_csv() method?

Tags: python-3.x

I am writting my data to a csv using to_csv("file_name") method which makes the first raw of the csv file 0, 1, 2, 3, ..... etc. Is there a way to keep the same method but just change the first raw to first_name, second_name, third_name?

Comment: `to_csv()` of what a pandas dataframe? Please give us something to go on to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I created a list and wrote the list to row using csv python library. Then I change the to_csv("file_name", method="a").